# Join paths of a live paint group - illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, cs6

Hi I am trying to join two paths in a live paint group. I am not sure whether this is possible or if I have to undo the live paint and ungroup it. I am a bit confused still with groups in illustrator and when the command+join works and when it doesn't. I have images below for reference, I also did a screenshot of the layers panel with the two paths named "join" inside the live paint group.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I just selected paths and clicked "expand" in top panel this seemed to solve the problem and the paths joined but stroke changed. I am still not 100% clear though on why it worked

Comment: I think the error dialog is clear enough. You can't use Join on a Live Paint group.  It's probably always best to use Live Paint on a copy of your artwork, so that you don't lose the original, so you can fix it if there are problems. Expanding works because it removes the Live Paint group.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not a perfect solution but you could use the pen tool to close the gaps. First select a end anchor point on one path and then click the end point of the other path. You can also remove the resulting extra anchor point with the pen tool.

Comment: Yes I think I know what you mean thanks :)